# How to set event handler functions in kivy templates?

Tags: python, kivy

Hej,

I want to create an TextInput or Label which is alligned to the center. A method is to create an AnchorLayout and attach it to it. Doing that to all labels can be an nasty coding task. Thats why I want to create a Template doing it for me. The pseudo code looks like this:

```
<myTextInput@AnchorLayout>:
    text: ''
    TextInput:
        text: root.text
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.on_text_validate
```

I whant to use myTextInput like a common TextInput. By defineing a text property and linking the TextInput text to it, it becomes possible to set the text.
BUT I did not figure out how to redirect the event handler like "on_text_validate" to the root. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that the AnchorLayout here is doing nothing? Since the textinput has no size defined and the default size_hint of `None, None`, it takes the same pos and size as the AnchorLayout.

Comment: I am aware of it. I want to use the TextInput in BoxLayouts with flexible scaling. For example: one non multiline textinput attached to the value of a slider. It needs to be centered to the slider(that the UI looks good). The same problem occures is with lables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there :)

For handlers (`on_xxx`), the right side of the Kv is executed as a function. So you juse need to add `()` to call your expression. If you want to pass the current args, just do:

```
on_text_validate: root.on_text_validate(*args)
```

Comment: In my case it does not work. When useing the template like:
`myTextInput:
    on_text_validate: print("hello")`
I got a kivy.lang.BuilderException with "KeyError: 'text_validate'"
I am useing kivy 1.8.0 + python 3.4

Comment: Careful, in your example, your handler is ok, on_text_validate is an event from the TextInput instanciated. In your comment, you seem to declared on_text_validate into the myTextInput directory (not in the TextInput child)

Comment: maybe my question should be: how to tunnel a event handler function given by the root to a child widget.